# How can I make good efficent AJAX live forms with just jQuery and

Tags: php, ajax

I've been trying to make AJAX forms but made no luck, I tried using iframes but I frames aren't that good. That's all I've tried, and that's all I know.

I have tried using the $.AJAX function but not sure how exactly to send data and receive it back

I have also used the AJAX load function, but that's also smt I counlt figure out on how to send data via.

I tried many pure JavaScript ways but there just too messy

And also, how can I return the variables back form the server to make the text box red and showerrors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send ajax request like this

**JQUERY code for sending ajax request to the server**

```
$.ajax({ method:"POST" url:"form.php", data: $("form").serialize(), dataType: 'json', success: function() {
    
    // code to run in success
    
},
    
    error: function() {
        
        // code to run on an error
        
    }

});
```

then you can return the data like this

**PHP code to return data back as json**

```php
// make sure that this is an array to send multiple data back
echo json_encode($data);
```

**PHP code to get data from client**

```php
$_REQUEST['username'];
```

and to read the data via JS , you should put this in our success function

**JS code to access returned json data from server**

```js
   data.name
 // ^     ^     ^
 // the first arrow is the php var
 // the second arrow is the array offset
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a simple example for you to search the names using keywords.

**action.php**

```
<?php
// Array with names
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Cinderella";
$a[] = "Diana";
$a[] = "Eva";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
if ($q !== "") {
  $q = strtolower($q);
  $len=strlen($q);
  foreach($a as $name) {
    if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
      if ($hint === "") {
        $hint = $name;
      } else {
        $hint .= ", $name";
      }
    }
  }
}
// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "action.php?q="+str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>
<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form action="">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
```